# Firebase Analytics: view_item's custom parameters are mostly (not set)

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have a Flutter app that records *view_item* events in Firebase Analytics. Here is the code:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logViewItem(
    items: [
        AnalyticsEventItem(
            itemId: myItem.id, 
            itemName: myItem.name, 
            itemCategory: myItem.category
        )
    ]
);
```

This event is correctly recorded in Firebase Analytics. However, the parameters (itemId, itemName, itemCategory) are mostly displayed as *(not set)*:

[image]

I don't understand why some ITEM CATEGORY and ITEM ID are correctly displayed but most of them are *(not set)*.

FYI, I have registered those parameters in my Custom Definitions:

[image]

Does anyone understand what wrong is going here?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is it possible that vast majority of your FB events don't have these fields set? item_category and item_id is exactly what I would expect to be only used in e-commerce or closely related events. You would see not sets for the rest of events. I'd suggest debugging your app, forcing it to log whatever's sent to FB (preferably not using FB's native logging) and seeing what's actually being sent. Well sniffing the network requests would be another valid approach here.

Comment: @BNazaruk I have already checked with the Firebase Analytics Debug View. And all my events seems to have the parameters attached :-/

Comment: And the attached params have meaningful values in the debug view? Not like 99% of them are nulls? We usually don't use Firebase for reporting and analysis. Only for debugging. Try linking it to GA4 and looking at the data from there.

Comment: The default value of the custom parameter dimension is an empty string which will also be evaluated as (not set). Make sure you're always passing values to all parameters logged with your view_item event.